# Python: Why does this non-blocking call to recv block?

Tags: python, sockets, blocking, nonblocking, recv

I have the following code in the $**init** call of a thread:

```
self.conn = copy.deepcopy(conn)
self.conn.setblocking(0)
```

conn is a socket and is passed as an argument to $**init**
Every thread recieves a unique socket. In the run method I have:

```
self.running = True
self.conn.send("Connected")
print self.name, "has a timeout of", self.conn.gettimeout()

while self.running:
    try:
        now = self.conn.recv(8192)
        print "Recieved:", now, "\n\tFrom:", self.name
        self.process(now)
    except socket.error:
         raise

     print "hi from", self.name
     time.sleep(1)
```

The timeout is printed as 0.0, but "hi from threadname" only printed out when a message is recieved and the exception is never raised! It looks as if the recv method blocks, but why would it do that?

Comment: Are you running this from IDLE?

Comment: If every thread gets a unique socket anyway, why are you making a copy?

Comment: @agf, I want to be sure that I keep the references correct.

Answer (score 1):

Propably because recv is reading from file and I/O is blocking? (sockets are files too as you may know) :)

Look here: [python socket.recv/sendall call blocking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2549788/python-socket-recv-sendall-call-blocking) for more info :)

Comment: Well, the socket is a port on the local host, I expect recv to reading from there. How can I validate this?